# Use mysql SET variables in db_query

Tags: database

How can I use mysql `SET` variables while using my PDO queries?

```
db_query('SET @x := 5,SET @y := 6, SELECT * from mytable')->fetchAll();
```

I have tried this and many variations of this statement with and without `':'` etc, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try just one statement per db_query call, it seems PDO only supports one statement per call. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685040/907592

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points here.

```
SET @x := 5,SET @y := 6, SELECT * from mytable" should be "SET @x := 5,SET @y := 6; SELECT * from mytable
```

as

```
SET @x := 5,SET @y := 6;" and "SELECT * from mytable
```

are 2 separate MySQL statements.

You can not execute multiple statements together using `db_query()`. Since the PHP functions `mysql_query()` and `mysqli_query()` can only execute one SQL statement, the `db_query()` wrapper can also only execute one SQL statement.

What you can do here is, divide that into two part and run it.

```
db_query('SET @x := 5,SET @y := 6;')->execute();
db_query('SELECT * from mytable')->fetchAll();
```